# How does WebDriver launch an instance of IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How does WebDriver launch an IE instance?

That is, what exactly does the IEDriverServer.exe do? How does this binary instantiate an IE browser window?

Comment: have you read this documentation already? https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Comment: Yes, I've gone through that doc before. It doesn't explain the mechanisms of how an IE browser is instantiated. For example, the FirefoxDriver launches a Firefox browser using a Firefox installation at the location specified in the parameter 'webdriver.firefox.bin'. For IE, WebDriver seems to launch a browser through IEDriverServer.exe? Is this correct?

Comment: the first paragraphs of the documentation says it all, "The driver (WebDriver) supports running 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the browser. The choice of how to determine which "bit-ness" to use in launching the browser depends on which version of the IEDriverServer.exe is launched. If the 32-bit version of IEDriverServer.exe is launched, the 32-bit version of IE will be launched. Similarly, if the 64-bit version of IEDriverServer.exe is launched, the 64-bit version of IE will be launched. "

Comment: How does IEDriverServer.exe know where the IE installation is to launch the browser?

Comment: it checks the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\

Comment: Except for very limited and rare circumstances, IEDriverServer.exe does no examination of the registry to determine the installed location of IE for the purposes of launching the browser. It does locate the executable to reliably get its version information, but that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a new session is requested by the language bindings, `IEDriverServer.exe` calls the Windows [`IELaunchURL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function on a "known good" URL. Usually, this is http://localhost:[port], but can be controlled by passing specific capabilities. With the introduction of Protected Mode in IE 7, [this API is the proper way to launch IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The driver connects to localhost instead of, say, about:blank, because the target URL must belong to a Protected Mode zone, and about:blank does not.

The `IELaunchURL` API is also required because with multi-process IE, the process started by simply launching `iexplore.exe` may not be the actual process containing the browser to be driven. The `IELaunchURL` API returns the process ID of the launched browser, which the driver can use to locate the window handle of the browser window owned by that `iexplore.exe` process. Once the window handle is known, the driver can use one of two techniques (either [Active Accessibility](https://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q249232) or the ShellWindows API) to get references to the IE COM objects it uses to actually drive the browser.

It is worth noting that, by default, the driver does not directly create an instance of IE via `CreateProcess`, and thus does not need to query the registry to locate the installed location of IE for the purposes of launching the browser. While the driver *does* determine the location of the IE executable, and uses the registry to do so, but it uses the location so that the driver can correctly and unambiguously determine the version of IE installed on the system.

Comment: Wonderful! This is exactly the information I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

IEDriverServer is a standalone HTTP server which implements WebDriver's JSON wire protocol - using which WebDriver controls IE.  IEDriverServer uses COM library registered in the machine to create an instance of the browser.

[image]
https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/JsonWireProtocol.wiki
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriverInternals#How_the_Works

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think it is worth defining what WebDriver is.
In definition and as the other answer mentioned, WebDriver implements the API which is language and platform independent and drives browsers through associated wire protocols. I would recommend you to read [this](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html) to learn about the internal architecture of WebDriver

> **Now what exactly does the IEDriverServer.exe do?**

IEDriverServer as well as other drivers can be considered as the interpreter of common WebDriver commands.

• So you write some command using Java, C#, python etc.

• You started executing those commands by running Selenium tests

•   Selenium kicks off IEDriver server(and other driver or whatever you are using) and the driver start listening to a free port

[image]

•   The Selenium commands are being intercepted by the driver and transfer to the browser through JSon protocol and drives the browser.
The answer provided by @Vinoth S show this whole process.

> **Secondly, How does this binary instantiate an IE browser window?**

As @Roman says IEDriver and all other drivers know where to look for in order to open a browser. That basically is the registry. If you go to the registry path @Roman mentioned you will see the exe location similar to this one. In my case the windows is in D drive but generally it's in C

[image]